# Aggregate likes from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js, facebook-like

I'm trying to aggregate the number of likes from all Facebook pages of a user. I'm using a `map` to go through each of the user's pages, grab the likes of that object, and add it to a variable.

```
{_(@state.fbPages).map((x) -> return likes: x.likes)}
```

But right now it's only adding all the likes in a row like this: 32049381. Is there something in the underscore.js library (or any other way) that can help me individualize these likes and aggregate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that it is adding all the likes into a string? i.e. is it taking an array like this `[3,2,0,4,9,3,8,1]` and your result is `32049381`? It may be storing individual likes as strings, and you will need to use `parseInt()`.

```
{_(@state.fbPages).map((x) -> return likes: parseInt(x.likes))}
```

I am sort of confused by your question but hopefully this is what you were looking for

Comment: I ended up approaching it with a for loop, but sorry for the confusing question. Parsing it into an int did solve the issue. Thanks!